# Как работает кодировка, и таблица символов

Tags: javascript, кодировка

Выставил, к примеру, в HTML-документе кодировку Windows-1251 (кириллица), ввожу строку «Егор» и средствами JavaScript выводу код этого символа:

```
var str = 'Егор';
str.charCodeAt(0);//1056
```

Результат — `1056`. Смотрю в [таблицу символов](http://pascal.net.ru/1251) и не могу понять, откуда взялся этот код.

Ищу информацию — везде только таблицы, и основные понятия (что такое кодировка).

Вопрос: как это все взаимосвязано и работает?

Answer (score 6):

По порядку.

1. Читая теорию по функции [charCodeAt()](https://learn.javascript.ru/string) узнаем следующее:

> **Все строки имеют внутреннюю кодировку Юникод**.
>
> Неважно, на каком языке написана страница, находится ли она в
>   windows-1251 или utf-8. Внутри JavaScript-интерпретатора все строки
>   приводятся к единому «юникодному» виду. Каждому символу соответствует
>   свой код.

Далее.

2. Изучая саму таблицу Юникода и ее организацию (полезное: [кириллические символы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5), [более наглядная таблица](http://unicode-table.com/ru/#greek-coptic)), узнаем, что символ кириллической буквы "Е" находится на позиции U+0415 (0x415 в шестнадцатиричной системе).
3. Все вышесказанное подтверждается результатом функции `"Е".charCodeAt(0)`, которая дает `1045`, а не `1056` как у вас. `1045 (dec) = 415 (hex)`
4. Смотрим в таблицу кодировки на строку `0410` и столбец `5`. На пересечении и есть наша буква `Е`.

```js
alert("Егор".charCodeAt(0));
```

Comment: а 1056 тогда откуда взялся?

Comment: @Sergey понятия не имею как этого добиться можно. Добавил пример в ответ.

Comment: Выставляю <meta charset="windows-1251">, и выводит 1056 код, если ставить utf8 - выводит 1045.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по результату вы сохранили файл в кодировке UTF-8. В это кодировке строке `Егор` соответствует последовательность байтов `d0 95 d0 b3 d0 be d1 80`.

Браузер увидев тег `<meta charset=windows-1251>` интерпретировал эту последовательность как 8 символов `Р•РіРѕСЂ`. Первый из них это русская буква «Р», и она имеет код 1056.